# Want To retrieve string from my array

Tags: c#

My string array contains below values

```
null
String 1 
String 2
String 3
null
String 4
String 5
String 6
null
String 7
String 8
String 9
```

I want to  retrieve

```
String 1 String 2 String 3
String 4 String 5 String 6
String 7 String 8 String 9
```

Comment: Is that expected return an array of 3 elements? ie, consisting of the first 3 string concatenated together, the second 3 and the third?

Comment: Is it an array or is it a file with `NewLine` characters?

Comment: Your earlier code has `NULL`, now its `null`, is it the null value in the string or "NULL" as a string in your array

Comment: @Jamiec need to concate first three 3 string concatenated together, the second 3 and the third.

Comment: so are u trying to get the sub-arrays between the `null`s or is it just sheer coincidence that your desired output came out that way?  can't tell for sure.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A little LINQ magic

```
var arr = new [] {null,"string1","string2","string3",null,"string4","string5","string6",null,"string7","string8","string9"};

var items = arr.Select( (item,index) => new {item, nextNull = Array.IndexOf(arr,null,index)} )
                           .GroupBy(x => x.nextNull)
                           .Where(x => x.Any(y => !String.IsNullOrEmpty(y.item)))
                           .Select(x => String.Join(" ",x.Select(y => y.item)));
```

Output:

```
string1 string2 string3
string4 string5 string6
string7 string8 string9
```

Live example: http://rextester.com/GOIT12899

Comment: that is great example...

Answer (score 2):

I suppose the null representation means a null string :

```
var array = arraySource.Where(n=> !string.IsNullOrEmpty(n)).ToArray();
```

Comment: He don't want to select "non-NullOrEmpty" strings, he want to split the array into groups determined by the index of "null". I assume that each group should be joined with a white-space then.

Answer (score 1):

If you have `NULL` as string in your array then you try:

```
string[] newArray = stringArray.Where(r => !r.Equals("null", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
                             .ToArray();
```

Comment: He don't want to select "non-null" strings, he want to split the array into groups determined by the index of "null". I assume that each group should be joined with a white-space.

Comment: @TimSchmelter, in that case, he would require a loop, but to be honest, the question is not clear at all,

Answer (score 1):

Here's a loop that does what you want:

```
string[] str = new[] { "null", "String 1", "String 2", "String 3", "null", "String 4", "String 5", "String 6", "null", "String 7", "String 8", "String 9" };
var newStr = new List<string>();
for (int i = 0; i < str.Length; i++)
{
    string current = str[i];
    if (current == "null")
    {
        int index = Array.IndexOf(str, "null", i + 1, str.Length - (i + 1));
        if (index >= 0)
        {
            newStr.Add(string.Join(" ", str.Skip(i + 1).Take(index - 1 - i)));
            i = index - 1;
        }
        else
        {
            if (i != str.Length - 1)
                newStr.Add(string.Join(" ", str.Skip(i + 1).Take(str.Length - i)));
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

It joins strings with a white-space at a specified index determined by the string `null`.

Answer (score 0):

You can try on these lines

```
string[] myArray = new[] { "Stack", null, "OverFlow" };
string[] nulless = myArray.Where(t => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(t)).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

Split it into defined parts but you need to use a list:

```
public static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> Split<T>(this IEnumerable<T> list, int parts)
        {
          return list.Select((item, index) => new {index, item})
                       .GroupBy(x => (x.index + 1) / (list.Count()/parts) + 1)
                       .Select(x => x.Select(y => y.item));
        }
```