# retrieve string from array in C#

Tags: c#

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Want To retrieve string from my array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13681277/want-to-retrieve-string-from-my-array)

My string array contains below values

```
NULL
String 1 
String 2
String 3
Null
String 4
String 5
String 6
Null
String 7
String 8
String 9
```

I want to  retrieve

```
String 1 String 2 String 3
String 4 String 5 String 6
String 7 String 8 String 9
```

Comment: What is wrong with your [current question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13681277/want-to-retrieve-string-from-my-array/13681290#13681346)

Comment: It seems as other guy.. asking the same question.. maybe colleagues :)

Answer (score 0):

You have to filter the string array as follows.

```
items = items.Where(s => !String.IsNullOrEmpty(s)).ToArray();
```

Then the output which you will get will not have any null values.

Regards,
Pavan.G